# Find Range in Values Lies

Tags: c#

I am having 109,728 values in my CSV [381 values in one line & total 288 lines]
I am finding min and max value in my CSV and based on it creating ranges.
Then comparing each value and finding range in which value lies.

For Example

- Min Value - 30
- Max Value - 31
- No of Range - 3
- Ranges are `[30 - 31,31 - 32,32 - 33]`

If first value is `30.5` then it will lie in first range, so count value of that range will be increased by `1`. I have return loop for it, the complete process takes 7 seconds which is too slow as per my requirement.

Please help me how can I reduce this time. I want to complete the whole process within 1 second.

Below is my code:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Imager Data" + "\\" + oldest.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values1 = line.Split(';');
    for (int i = 0; i < 381; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text); j++)
        {
            if (lowerlimit[j] <= double.Parse(values1[i]) && double.Parse(values1[i]) <= upperlimit[j])
            {
                textboxArray[j].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textboxArray[j].Text) + 1).ToString();
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: Instead of converting the values in the text boxes to an `int` and incrementing it and then converting back to a string to put back in the text boxes, just keep track of all the values in an `int[]` and update the text boxes at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to reduce the amount of converting and parsing you are doing and limit the number of times you access the UI elements.  You can do that by keeping track of the values you want to increment in a `List<int>` and update the text boxes at the end.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Imager Data" + "\\" + oldest.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values1 = line.Split(';');
    int textBoxCount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
    List<int> textBoxValues = textboxArray
        .Take(textBoxCount)
        .Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Text)).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 381; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < textBoxCount; j++)
        {
            double numberValue = double.Parse(values1[i]);
            if (lowerlimit[j] <= numberValue && numberValue <= upperlimit[j])
            {
                textBoxValues[j]++;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < textBoxCount; j++)
    {
        textboxArray[j] = textBoxValues[j].ToString();
    }
}
reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: The time reduced to 77ms.Thanks it works.Minute change is there    
        textboxArray[j].Text = textBoxValues[j].ToString(); should be there.

Answer (score 0):

When you optimize you look at the lines of code that are executed the most times. In your inner look you are writing to a text box 1,09,728 times. That's what is slowing you down. Take out the screen updates by removing the reference to the text box in

```
textboxArray[j].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textboxArray[j].Text) + 1).ToString();
```

This will speed you up significantly.